# PeerJS - connection.on('open') not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, p2p, peerjs

1. When peer 1 connects to peer 2

   1. the highlighted code in the picture should fire
   2. peer 2 should send peer 1 "hello!"
   3. peer 1 should have "hello!" printed in its console
2. Peer 1 connects to peer 2
3. **Problem:** **peer 1 does not have "hello!" printed in its console**

[image]

```
// make a new peer
const peer = new Peer('', {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001'
});


// "connection" event fires when someone tries to connect to us
peer.on('connection', (conn) => {  
  console.log('someone connected');
  
  // "data" event fires when someone sends us a message
  conn.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
  
  // ===========================================================================
  
  // Problem: Both Attempt 1 and Attempt 2 fail to run
  
  // ATTEMPT 1: "open" event fires when the connection is opened
  conn.on('open', () => {
    conn.send('hello!');
  });
  
  // ATTEMPT 2:
  conn.send('hello!');
  // ===========================================================================
});


// connect to a peer
const conn = peer.connect('another-peers-id');


// after connecting to peer, send "hi" to them
conn.on('open', () => {
  conn.send('hi!');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there might be a problem with the connection itself.

After you do this

```js
const peer = new Peer('', {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001'
});
```

a new peer object is created and retured but, socket takes a bit of time to open up.
You can check this if you set the debug to 3,

[image: console]

If connect function is called before getting socket open, `connect` will fail

```js
const conn = peer.connect('another-peers-id');
```

You can try add a `setTimeout` for `connect` to test this theory.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
     const conn = peer.connect('id');
}, 1000);
```

And same problem exists with `'connection'` callback also
You can add setTimeout inside connection callback too

```js
peer.on("connection", (conn) => {
    console.log("Connected to: " + conn.peer);
    setTimeout(() => {
       ...enter code here...
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a server side for you PeerJS

run a free cloud-hosted version of PeerServer for testing , just change the

```
const peer = new Peer('', {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001'
});
```

to

```
var MyPeerId ;
const peer = new Peer();
```

and to get an id use :

```
  peer.on('open',  function(){
  MyPeerId = peer.id;
});
//this is an async function so you have be sure that you got an id before connection to someone else

//rest of your code here

function Connect(OtherPeerId){
 if(!MyPeerId)
 return 0; // you didn't get a peerid yet
 //rest of your code
 }
```

Comment: I have a peer server running on port 3001. That part is fine.